# textarea content auto clears whenever i click the form submit button [PHP]

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a textarea with a form submit button. Whenever I click the submit button, the content on my textarea clears. but i dont want to clear the content of my textarea. here is my code

### codepage.php

```
<?php

$ans = "hello";

if (isset($_POST['textcode'])) {
    {
        if ($_POST['textcode'] == $ans) {
            echo "<div id=errorPlace>proceed to next lesson</div>";
        }

        else
        {
            echo "<div id=errorPlace>Error</div>";
        }
    }

}
?>


<form  method="POST" name="validatePHP">
    <textarea name="textcode"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" title="Submit Code" name="add" value=""></input>
    </form>
```

---

thanks for the answers! It worked. now i have another question, what if the textarea has already a preloaded text in it and when I type in another text in it and click the submit button, the textarea should have now have the text that i inputted and the preloaded text in the textarea.

here is my updated code

```
<?php

$ans = "hello";


if (isset($_POST['textcode'])) {
    {
        if ($_POST['textcode'] == $ans) {
            echo "<div id=errorPlace>proceed to next lesson</div>";

        }

        else
        {
            echo "<div id=errorPlace>Error</div>";
        }
    }

}
?>

<form  method="POST" name="validatePHP">
    <textarea name="textcode"><?php if(isset($_POST['textcode'])) { 
     echo htmlentities ($_POST['textcode']); }?>hell</textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" title="Submit Code" name="add" value=""></input>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea name="textcode">
<?php if(isset($_POST['textcode'])) { 
     echo htmlentities ($_POST['textcode']); }?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but what if i have a preloaded text in my textarea ? and i dont want to completely reset the content of it ? example, I type in some text in the textarea which has already have a preloaded content and when i click the submit button, the text that the user input will add with the content in the textarea.

Answer (score 3):

Try render content after submit

```
<textarea name="textcode"><?= $_POST['textcode']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but what if i have a preloaded text in my textarea ? and i dont want to completely reset the content of it ? example, I type in some text in the textarea which has already have a preloaded content and when i click the submit button, the text that the user input will add with the content in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it with $_SESSION?

at the top of your page type `session_start();`
then inside

```
 if ($_POST['textcode'] == $ans) {
     echo "<div id=errorPlace>proceed to next lesson</div>";
 }
```

add the code `$_SESSION['textareaMsg'] = $_POST['textcode'];` like this...

```
 if ($_POST['textcode'] == $ans) {
     echo "<div id=errorPlace>proceed to next lesson</div>";
     $_SESSION['textareaMsg'] = $_POST['textcode'];
 }
```

then where your text area is set just replace it with this.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['textareaMsg'])){
        echo '<textarea name="textcode">'.$_SESSION['textareaMsg'].'</textarea>';
    }else{
         echo '<textarea name="textcode"></textarea>';
    }
?>
```

This works by saving the text area as a session variable when you submit the form, and checking if its set when you load the form, if it is then it will replace the contents of the text area with what is set in the session. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks it worked, but what if i have a preloaded text in my textarea ? and i dont want to completely reset the content of it ? example, I type in some text in the textarea which has already have a preloaded content and when i click the submit button, the text that the user input will add with the content in the textarea.

Comment: It should do that, if you change the content in the text area and re-submit it should add the changed text into the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
   <?php

        $ans = "hello";

        $textcode = ""; //declare a variable without value to avoid undefined error

        if (isset($_POST['textcode'])) {
            {
                $textcode=$_POST['textcode']; //assign the value to variable in you if statment
                if ($textcode == $ans) { //useing variable in if statment

                    echo "<div id=errorPlace>proceed to next lesson</div>";
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "<div id=errorPlace>Error</div>";
                }
            }

        }
        ?>


        <form  method="POST" name="test.php">
            <!--echo user input -->
           <textarea name="textcode"><?php echo $textcode; ?></textarea>

            <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" title="Submit Code" name="add" value=""></input>
        </form>
```